# How to write this SQL Command

Tags: sql

I am trying to select items from a table that contains the followings columns: `productName`, `ProductPrice` and `ProductCategory`. The products in this table have been categorised into Alcoholic and Soft Drinks.

I am trying to write a SQL statement that will select the `productName` and `ProductPrice`, but only select the products that have been categorized as soft drinks and leave out the the products that have been categorised as Alcoholic.

My SQL so far that i am trying to write is;

```
SELECT * 
FROM Products 
WHERE ProductPrice BETWEEN =''100' AND '300'" ...
```

This where I am stuck, how do I only select products that have categorised as 'Soft Drinks'

Comment: We're going to need more table structure to answer this question. Is there a linked table with, "ProductCategory" classified? Or is it just a matter of saying ProductPrice BETWEEN =''100' AND '300'" AND ProductCategory <> "Alcoholic"  Also note that you are currently using strings as numbers, which may be problematic.  That price should be converted to some kind of number before you try a between on it, just for safety's sake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is good,

```
SELECT * FROM Products 
WHERE ProductPrice BETWEEN '100' AND '300'
```

Here's what you need to add -

```
AND ProductCategory = 'Soft Drinks'
```

To get the final query -

```
SELECT * FROM Products 
WHERE ProductPrice BETWEEN '100' AND '300'
AND ProductCategory = 'Soft Drinks'
```

Comment: `WHERE ProductPrice BETWEEN ='100' AND '300'`  Can you seen an extra `=` :)

Comment: Thanks, I just copy/pasted from OP

Answer (score 2):

```
select
    productname,
    productprice
from 
    productsTable
where 
    price between 100 and 300
    and productcategory = "soft drinks";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM Products 
WHERE ProductPrice >= 100   --<-- If Product Price is Character datatype then use
AND ProductPrice   <= 300   --Single quotes else just the numbers without quotes 
AND productcategory = 'soft drinks'
```